# Why did Goku recruit Frieza but not gotenks

Tags: dragon-ball-super

Goku didn't recruit goten and trunks because they charge at their enemies like an idiot. But isn't Frieza like that as well? Why did Goku recruit Master Roshi who can't even beat Raditz? He can't even scratch the fighters from other universes. Roshi & Tien can be removed and leave space for Gotenks.

Comment: Well, removing Roshi and Tien would let Goten and Trunks enter. But when they fight as Gotenks, there would be one member less on the Universe 7 side. Therefore, number disadvantage, and hence reduced teamwork. Plus, Goten and Trunks aren't considered because of their childish nature. Which is proven by assigning them to protect the island.

Comment: Before you go disparaging Roshi for not being able to beat Raditz, I'd like to remind you of another character (whose name rhymes with Shmoku) that also couldn't beat Raditz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotenks has a time limit plus we dont know if fused characteres are allowed. Probably not, since fusion would end before the tournament and you would have 11 members in the arena when 10 members are allowed.

Freezer is way much stronger than Gotenks. Gotenks SSJ3 was less strong than duplicate Vegeta in base form https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1Jxo4gDdzs . Vegeta and Goku are in a similar level. Freezer is said by Beerus to be in the same level than SSB Goku.

Roshi can beat Raditz by far now. He could handle many Freezer soldiers, he could beat Tien who was able to defeat Burter and Jeice who were over Vegeta's 30000 power level of that time (probably between 40000 - 45000) . Tien could also hold second form Cell, deflect a Majin Buu Gohan absorbed attack, resist a punch in the stomach from mystic Gohan and not pass out, etc. Also Roshi, Krilin and Tien experience are taken into account. In a sparring match, Krilin defeated Gohan by pushing him outside of the arena, outsmarting him. He almost outsmarts Goku in a sparring match too, in spite of being much less weaker than them just like Tien and Roshi are.

Comment: There's no way Gotenks Ssj3 can lose to base form Vegeta. Base Gotenks can already hold super buu. And Ssj3 is 400 times stronger than base. It's just a filler.

Comment: @yuankai there are no fillers now. Neither the anime and the manga are directly written by Toriyama. He just gives general guidelines. They have plenty of room to add ideas of their own

Comment: @yuankai btw, base form using god ki is different than regular base form. Goku in base form using god ki could defeat Freezer 4th form, when Gohan super saiyan was almost killed by Freezer 1st form. That's what we saw in Dragon Ball Super and Fukkatsu no F. Vegeta in base form using god ki is stronger than SSJ3 Gotenks, no surprise here, since using god ki makes you about equally stronger than Super Saiyan God (red) , and Super Saiyan God Red is stronger than Super Saiyan 3 by far. It's like if Vegeta Super Saiyan God (red) would be fighting SSJ3 Gotenks